# Where is SQLite Database stored

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I know that it is stores in `/data/data/ + "packageName" + "/databases/"`
and I tried it in android 4.3 and it was correct.

but I see a code that say for android 4.2 the path is different. is it correct? or it is same for both.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2){
    DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";         
} else {
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + ""packageName"" + "/databases/";
}
```

I tried this for android 4.3 but not work:

```
DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
```

Comment: dont use hardcoded paths, read `android.content.Context` docs for an API to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQLite database <= Android 4.1, would be in `/data/data/<your_app_package_name>/`. However, you can only get to that directory on the emulator and on rooted devices. On Android 4.2 and higher, the path to internal storage depends on the user account.

Normally, unless previously specified, the SQLite database is stored in

`/data/data/<your_app_package_name>/databases/<database_name>`

You can see where the database is stored by running your application in an emulator, and by

1. Opening DDMS view
2. Navigate to `/data/data/<your_app_package_name>/databases`

Use `getDatabasePath()` to find out where it is being stored.

Answer (score 1):

> but I see a code that say for android 4.2 the path is different

No, this code does not say database is stored in somewhere else. It is only a hard-coded way to get a reference to where our database is stored.

If you want to get a reference to your home directory, you could use `getFilesDir()` of your activity. It returns an object of type `File` pointing to the files directory of your app.

Answer (score 1):

`Context` has the `getDatabasePath(String name)` method which returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a database created with openOrCreateDatabase is stored. It will return the path you are looking for up to name. To get the database directory passa an empty string to the method